# Unable to install gnome environment on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, dependencies, budgie, 23.10

I was using ubuntu 23.04 with gnome. After the update to ubuntu 23.10, it has shifted to budgie. I did not find any cog icon to switch environments on login page.
Here is the command I ran`sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.
This is the output in the terminal

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdm3 : Depends: libgdm1 (= 44.1-1ubuntu1) but 45~beta-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
        Recommends: ubuntu-session but it is not installable or
                    gnome-session but it is not installable or
                    x-session-manager
 gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-4.0 (= 44.0-1) but 44.0-2 is to be installed
 gir1.2-mutter-12 : Depends: libmutter-12-0 (= 44.1-1ubuntu1) but 44.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: gir1.2-json-1.0 (>= 0.13.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 : Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0 (= 0.105-33) but 123-1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (= 0.105-33) but 123-1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-pipewire : Depends: pipewire (= 0.3.71-1) but 0.3.79-2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0 (= 0.3.71-1) but 0.3.79-2 is to be installed
 nautilus : Depends: libnautilus-extension4 (= 1:44.1-1ubuntu1) but 1:45~rc-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: tracker (>= 3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: tracker-miner-fs (>= 3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: tracker-extract (>= 3) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not installable
                  Recommends: fonts-liberation2 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not installable
                  Recommends: yaru-theme-gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not installable
                          Recommends: fonts-liberation2 but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not installable
                          Recommends: yaru-theme-gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: gnome-session but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Could someone please help me out with the steps to change the desktop environment to gnome?

Comment: @user535733 Thank you, the issue was indeed with an incomplete upgrade. I changed the update server and tried once again, the update completed as expected. I was then able to switch to Gnome as expected. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

this is what I did to fix my broken update:

```
apt purge gnome-shell
apt purge ubuntu-desktop
apt autoremove -y
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```